# Recursive Continued Fraction - $x_{n+1} = 1 + \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x_n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continued-fractions

I have a sequence defined as such: $x_{n+1} = 1 + \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x_n}}$

When calculating the limit of this recursive sequence, I get $$L = 
\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$$ I've deduced that if $x_n > 0$ or $x_n <-1$, it must converge to a positive limit, but I am having trouble with $-1 < x_n < 0$. Is it ever possible for such sequence to converge to $- \phi$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What if you start with $-\phi$?

Comment: It might help you to study the [*cobweb plot*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_plot) of the map $f(x)=\frac{2x+1}{x+1}$. If we write $\alpha=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\beta=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ for the zeros of $x=f(x)$, then $(x_n)$ converges to $\beta$ unless $x_n=\alpha$ for all $n$ or $x_n=-1$ for some $n$.

Comment: Alternatively, if we define $$z_n = \frac{x_n - \alpha}{\beta - x_n},$$ then it is not hard to check that $$z_{n+1}=\beta^4 z_n.$$ Using this, it is easy to conclude that $z_n\to\pm\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ unless $z_n=0$, and this implies $x_n\to\beta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible limits of $(x_n)$ are fixed points of $g(x)=\frac{2x+1}{x+1}$. Since $|g'(-\phi)|>1$, the convergence to $-\phi$ is only possible if $x_{n_0} = -\phi$, for some $n_0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x_0 \in (-1, \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})$ then the sequence is decreasing to $-\infty$.
If $x_0 \in (\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}, 0)$ the sequence is convergent to $\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}.$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x_1>0$. Then $x_n>0$ for all $n\ge2$. Let
$$ \alpha=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2},\beta=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}. $$
Since
$$ x_2-x_1=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x_1}}-x_1=-\frac{x_1^2-x_1-1}{1+x_1}=-\frac{(x_1-\alpha)(x_1-\beta)}{1+x_1} $$
and
$$ x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x_n}}-\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x_{n-1}}}=\frac{x_n-x_{n-1}}{x_{n-1}x_n\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x_n}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x_{n-1}}}\right)}$$
we have that, if $x_1=\beta$, then $\{x_n\}=\{\beta\}$ is a constant sequence; if $x_1<\beta$, $\{x_n\}$ is increasing; and $x_1>\beta$ is decreasing. Thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ is either finite or infinite. Clearly the limit is not infinite. Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$. Then
$$ x=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac1x} $$
which gives $x=\beta$. If $x_1<0$, you treat similarly and I omit the detail.